# Get Google Map Place id using Place

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have 100 place names and I need to collect Google Maps place ids of these place names using automated JavaScript.

I found this [Google Example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-placeid-finder) to get `place_id` using place names.

But, I need to collect `place_id`'s programmatically. Suggest me how to get this.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox
Use that. Instead of 'searchBox.addListener' implement your own method. Then extract place id from place objects.

Comment: I am wondering about downvote, because please mention the reason,  I need to edit question.

Comment: TL;DR: Too generic. What have you accomplished - where are you stuck? 
EDIT: Now I understand your problem, because i looked closer at the example. The problem is, that you cannot programmatically control the input and suggestions of the autocomplete object in an obvious way. That should've been worded more clearly in your question.

Comment: Ever find an answer for this?

Answer (score -1):

Referring to my comment above and my current understanding of your question described in there, here is my suggestion.

You cannot access and control the "Autocomplete"-gui-object in an obvious manner. Instead you should use the "AutocompleteService"-object and its getPlacePredictions() method.

You should read up on the [AutocompleteService reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#AutocompleteService) and i suggest you also take a close look at the AutocompletionRequest (right below AutocompleteService  on the same page) which is an important parameter needed for the method getPlacePredictions() which you will want to use.